# No HUD on desktop on new Ubuntu installation

Tags: 12.04, display, hud

So I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I have no HUD. I was able to bring up Firefox only from my settings menu by clicking on a link for more information on cloud. Where is my HUD? I have no access to my programs at all?

Comment: For HUD press `Alt` under any open application, for application menu press `Super+A`, or Via DASH menu., assuming you are using Unity Desktop.

Comment: welcome to Ubuntu! Can you post a screenshot, or describe what you expect to see, and what you actually see, to give us a better idea of what you're dealing with? (Not an Answer, but I can't find a way to use AskUbuntu to comment on your question, only answer it.)

Comment: This is what I got. I'm a rookie by the way. Super + A doesnt wark nor does Alt. I can't post a screenshot because the hud is missing and navigation is nearly impossible. i have noticed that my graphics card isn't installed. It comes up as unknown in the overview section?

Comment: I'm assuming its a graphics driver issue due to the fact that none of my sliders for graphics adjustments work?

Comment: Dell Inspiron M5030 Laptop

Comment: Do you have a `printscreen` button on your keyboard. Please use that to add screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If the HUD is not working, then you should select Ubuntu 2D at the login screen to avoid the issue for now and give you a working desktop. Then, if there is an underlying problem, it will be easier to find and to fix.

1. click on the cog at the login screen
2. select Ubuntu 2D from the dropdown menu:

[image: how to choose unity 2d]

Comment: The only option that shows up when I do this is the back button. None of the items in your screenshot show up?